# ORM error when password passed to mongodb from sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm trying to use sails.js with MongoDB as the database and I think I am doing some basic mistake, but can't figure out what it is (yup, a little on the newbie side to both of these frameworks):

If I use the default mongo connection code in sails there doesn't seem to be a problem and it seems to connect fine:

```
someMongodbServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017, }
```

Now if I add a 'user' to this connection it works as well:

```
someMongodbServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017,
user: 'someusername', }
```

The weird thing starts here, in that it works also if I input a user name that doesn't exist in my MongoDB setup.

And when I do it with a password like this -

```
someMongodbServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017,
user: 'someusername',
password: '1111', }
```

It throws the following error and refuses to start the server:

```
A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
```

Just to check, I input the user name and password to MongoDB via the terminal like this:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "someusername" -p "1111" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

And it works alright, so this user exists and this is the password (right?).

I can't even figure out if the problem is in my mongo setup or in sails.

Comment: Try adding " database: 'database_name_here" beneath password. Just a suggestion, no promises - please report back if it makes any difference. What version of sailsJs and sails-mongo adapter are you using?

Comment: It didn't make a difference - still, with and without the database info, having a password does not let the server start, and having a username seems to have no effect at all.  I am using the latest versions: sails v0.11.2 and sails-mongo v0.11.5

Comment: login in to mongo from the command line and do not specify the username and password. do you gain access?  Also try logging in from sailsjs without username or password, and actually use sailsjs to update some collection inside your mongo database. In other words, verify that sailsjs is happily performing CRUD ops (via waterline). Let me know outcome - depending on what it is - we may have isolated the problem down to your mongo authentication setup.

Comment: so: it's possible to access mongo from the command line without username and password (a wrong username or password though, don't work). Sails does use the database as expected - or so I think. When I POST via sails the result is later seen, via sails. However, when I try to view this in mongo (using db.collection.find().pretty()) there's no visible results. The collection, however, does exist (when I use show collections). I am very confused.

Comment: Take a look inside your config/connections.js file - which adapter is enabled? (uncommented). Make sure it is only the mongoServer adapter settings (comment everything else out). Also, you will see a .tmp folder in the base of your project. Do yoiu see a localDiskDb.db file? If so delete it, and see whether your results are still visible when you start up your app now? From what you've told me so far a). your mongo authorization isn't setup correctly, and b). there is doubt whether sails is actually successfully talking to mongo at the moment. Is it using localDisk instead?

Comment: Ok, so this is what happened: a short while after the last comment was made my computer died. As in - the hard drive had to be replaced by a new one. Upon re-installing mongo and sails on a blank new hard drive everything seems to be running smoothly. This leads me to think that whatever had happened was because of the malfunctioning hard drive, which apparently had problems because of the OS encrypting things out of order, but that is a very un-educated guess. I have no way of re-creating the problem, so I guess will never know for sure what had been the problem. Thanks for the comments !

Comment: lol, no probs and pleased to hear you are back up and running.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mongodb with authenticationDatabase by using

`MongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    username: 'xxxx', //optional
    password: 'xxxx', //optional
    database: 'xxxx', //Database u need to connect to,
    authenticationDatabase: 'admin' // Database you want use for authentication
  },`

Before doing so ensure you have the database created using
`use admin`

Then create the username/password and database with permissions

`db.createUser({ user:"<USER_NAME>", pwd: "<PASSWORD>", roles: [{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}] })`

Read more about MongoDB roles here: [MongoDB Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

If you dont specify the authenticationDatabase, mongo defaults to same database for authentication purposes and looks in the user table.